# Java: error: cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called

Tags: java, constructor, imageicon

I'm trying to add a constructor to the `javax.swing.ImageIcon`. It shall resolve the directory structure to be able to access the `ImageIcon` class like a image map.

What I'm trying to do is:

```
public class CPImageIcon extends ImageIcon {

    public CPImageIcon(String name) {

        super(this.getClass().getResource("/desktopapplication1/resources/" + name), "description");
    }
```

but this leads to:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
I:\DesktopApplication1\src\desktopapplication1\CPImageIcon.java:18: error: cannot reference this before supertype constructor has been called
        super(this.getClass().getResource("/desktopapplication1/resources/" + name),"");
```

If I try to super other constructors it works.

Comment: Do you really need to extend `ImageIcon`? Could you not just use a factory method to construct an instance of `ImageIcon` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`super` constructor must be the first call in subclasses constructors.
If ommitted it will call automatically to default constructor `super()`.

`this` represent the current instance, and can't be used before calling super.

You could use the following approach, commented or uncommented:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class CPImageIcon extends ImageIcon {

    public CPImageIcon(String name) {
        super(CPImageIcon.class.getResource("/desktopapplication1/resources/" + name), "description");
//        super(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("/desktopapplication1/resources/" + name), "description");
    }
}
```